# How to combine GET & POST HTTP methods for the same view in Spring web app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have a view that is rendered with this method:

```
@RequestMapping("/employee/{id}")
public String showSpecificEmployee(@PathVariable String id, Model model){

    model.addAttribute("employee", employeeService.findEmployeeById(new Long(id)));

    DateCommand dateCommand = new DateCommand();
    dateCommand.setEmployeeId(new Long(id));

    model.addAttribute("date", dateCommand);

    return "specificEmployee";
}
```

The view displayes some basic information about the `Employee`. On the same view, I do have a form to choose a month and filter the information by `Date`. 
After the `Date` is chosen, I would like to have the view 'refreshed' with updated information. That means I do have a POST & GET methods bound to the same view.

```
@RequestMapping("/passdate")
public String updateWorkmonth(@ModelAttribute DateCommand dateCommand, Model model){

    model.addAttribute("employee", employeeService.findEmployeeWithFilteredWorkdaysAndPayments(dateCommand.getEmployeeId(), dateCommand.getActualDate()));
    model.addAttribute("date", dateCommand);

    return "specificEmployee";
}
```

After the second method is invoked looks like
`http://localhost:8080/passdate?employeeId=1&actualDate=2018-02`, but I want it to be `/employee/{id}`. How do I combine those 2 methods, so they point to the same URL?

If I set `@RequestMapping("/employee/{id}")` on both methods, I keep getting an error.

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987380/combine-get-and-post-request-methods-in-spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need only **one** GET method

```
@RequestMapping("/employee/{id}")
```

and optionally passed

```
@RequestParam("actualDate")
```

Comment: oh.. Do I need to pass the Date backing object too?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the type of `HTTP` request you want in the `@RequestMapping` parametters

When you don't specify it, it uses `GET` by default

`@RequestMapping(value = "/employee/{id}",method = RequestMethod.POST)`

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect user to that url. Just replace in method `updateWorkmonth` one line

```
return "specificEmployee";
```

with

```
return "redirect:/employee/" + dateCommand.getEmployeeId();
```

Comment: This thing is it will not filter Employee information as it will invoke method bound to this URL. And that is initial data.